# How to add two string in C programming language?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, concatenation

How to add two string in C?

Have a look at my program that I have made so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char samrat[10]="*";
    char string[1]="*";
    samrat=samrat+string;
}
```

Comment: did you try `strcat()` ?

Comment: @deamentiaemundi: No; not really. https://www.google.com/search?q=c+add+strings

Comment: @SLaks Reseaching yourself? Asking Google even? No, *that* would be waaay too much! ;-) But serious: it was meant as a little stinger for those users here who think that every poster is highly fluent in English and I was quite serious with "third or fourth" language. Be a more patient, pleeease!

Answer (score 3):

Use standard C function `strcat` declared in header `<string.h>`. For example

```
#include <string.h>

//...

strcat( samrat, string );
```

Another approach is to create dynamically a new string that will contain the concatenation of these two strings. For example

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//...

char *s = malloc( strlen( samrat ) + strlen( string ) + 1 );

if ( s != NULL )
{
    strcpy( s, samrat );
    strcat( s, string );
}

//...

free( s );
```

As for your statement

```
samrat=samrat+string;
```

then array designators are converted (with rare exceptions) to pointers to their first elements in expressions. So you are trying to add two pointers. This operation for pointers is not defined in C. And moreover arrays are non-modifiable lvalues. You may not assign an array with an expression.

Comment: Perhaps you should recommend him to allocate/malloc a new buffer equal to the length of both strings?

Answer (score 1):

`samrat + string` will attempt to add together two pointers of type `char*`, with a meaningless result.

Use `strcat` to concatenate two strings: `strcat(samrat, string);`. Don't forget to ensure that the `samrat` buffer is large enough to accommodate the result.